# Ecto - preload only the most recent record

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to write an Ecto query where I am querying for many records and for each record wish to preload only the most recent record from a related table; however, things aren't quite working out as I'd like. Say, for example, I have a data model with many `users` where each has many `comments` - the result I'm trying to achieve is a list of all users where each has only their most recent published comment preloaded.

The closest I've been able to muster is

```
# assume that my User model has a `has_many(:comments)` relationship defined

defp preload_most_recent_comment(_user_ids) do
  Comment
  |> where([c], c.status == :published)
  |> last(:inserted_at)
  |> Repo.all()
end

def get_users_with_most_recent_comment() do
  User
  |> preload([comments: ^(&preload_most_recent_comment/1)])
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

however, the problem here is that it doesn't preload *each* user's most recent published comment - it only preloads the single most recent published comment and puts it on the associated user... so the results look something like

```
[
  %User{
    id: 1,
    comments: [%{id: 1, status: "published", inserted_at: ~U[2022-01-01 00:00:00]}]
  },
  %User{
    id: 2,
    comments: []
  }
]
```

even though user `2` has a published comment. If I remove the `last` statement, then the preload works essentially the way I'd like it to, albeit that it returns multiple comments for each user, rather than just the most recent.

What is the appropriate way to adjust this query so that each preload is not only filtered by something like `status`, but also limited to only the most recent record?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, a lot of sleuthing and trial & error led me to a solution using a windowing function... here's how it all went down in the end. **EDIT:** the query below actually wasn't quite correct - it would actually return multiple comments per user - leaving it for posterity and comparison, but **see the revised version below that for the "real" working version...**

```
defp most_recent_comment() do
  Comment
  |> select([c], %{c | inserted_at: over(last_value(c.inserted_at), :user)})
  |> windows([c], [user: [partition_by: c.user_id, order_by: [desc: c.inserted_at]]])
end

defp preload_published_comments(_) do
  Comment
  |> where([c], c.status == :published)
  |> join(:inner, [c], rc in subquery(most_recent_comment()), on: c.id == rc.id)
  |> Repo.all()
end

def get_users_with_most_recent_published_comment() do
  User
  |> preload([comments: ^(&preload_published_comments/1)])
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

**Ok, here's the "correct" version**, making use of `row_number()` and moving the `where` clause to the subquery -

```
defp most_recent_published_comment() do
  Comment
  |> where([c], c.status == :published)
  |> select([c], %{id: c.id, row_number: over(row_number(), :user_id_partition)})
  |> windows([_], [user_id_partition: [partition_by: :user_id, order_by: [desc: :inserted_at]]])
end

defp preload_published_comments(_) do
  Comment
  |> join(:inner, [c], rc in subquery(most_recent_published_comment()),
    on: c.id == rc.id and rc.row_number == 1
  )
  |> Repo.all()
end

def get_users_with_most_recent_published_comment() do
  User
  |> preload([comments: ^(&preload_published_comments/1)])
  |> Repo.all()
end
```

There is documentation around this at https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries, but I still had to muck about for a while. Hope this is helpful!

Other useful windowing documentation from Ecto - https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.WindowAPI.html

Comment: Thanks for posting this, helped me tremendously.  The docs link was super helpful.